# Integrate (numerically) $\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^x(x) \, dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How can we calculate the integration $\int_0^{2\pi} \sin^x(x) \, dx$ numerically?

I tried calculating it using Simpson's rule and trapezoidal rule using python program; but it gave 'nan'.

Mathematica's NInregrate[(Sin[x])^x,{x,0,2 Pi}] gives 1.77788+ i 0.364092.

What would be the approach to solve this?

(I am quite puzzled, why does this have an imaginary solution?  This part is solved)

Comment: Between $\pi$ and $2 \pi$, the equation $\sin^x(x)$ is not defined, as $\sin(x) \lt 0$, and $a^x, a \lt 0$ is not defined for all numbers, only integers:https://www.desmos.com/calculator/gpbagrwj7d

Answer (score 2):

The integral cannot be computed over **reals** as there are many points of discontinuity for $\pi<x< 2\pi$.

Eg. For $\pi<x<2\pi$,  $\sin(x) $ is negative. Say $x = \pi + \frac{\pi}{6} = \frac{7\pi}{6}$. Then your function is of the form $$\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{6}\right) ^{\frac{7\pi}{6}} = \left(\frac{-1}{2}\right)^{\frac{7\pi}{6}}$$

Which evidently enough is **not real**.

The problem lies with the fact that $(f(x))^{x}$ is not well defined when $f(x) < 0$ because of many points of discontinuity.

Alternatively, you can easily calculate the integral for $x\in (0,\pi)$ and we would not have this problem.

Comment: Thank you. You explained it making it so easy :) .

By the way, what would be the way to compute the integral?

Comment: I mean $f(z) = \Re(f(z)) + i \Im(f(z))$